# What am I doing wrong that is throwing an "Error in fun(file) : Unsupported file format." error

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have a folder of images, all .jpeg, which I am trying to load into R.  I am getting the following error

> Error in fun(file) :  Unsupported file format. 
>   Please convert to jpeg/png/bmp or install image magick

I have tried reinstalling the `imager` and `magick` packages, neither has solved the issue.

In the Files tab of RStudio I have made sure that the images exist there and are selected.

```
library(imager)
library(magick)

image1 = load.image('image1.jpeg')
plot(image1)
```

I would expect to see the image pop up in the plots tab, but it is not.

Comment: Are you sure those are actually jpeg images? A file can have any extension; it doesn't actually mean it's necessarily a jpeg. If you are on windows, some ways to test can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1245611/how-to-identify-a-file-type-without-extension-in-windows).

Comment: I'll go check that link out, but is it not sufficient to simply select the image in the directory, go to properties and then verify that it says .jpeg? If not, that seems bizarre?

Comment: I just renamed a file on my computer from JPG to GIF. Windows incorrectly reported it with whatever file name it had. It even still opened it and didn't warn of the mismatch. These types of files have "magic numbers" in them that say what they really R, but windows doesn't seem to verify that from Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use magick's `image_read()` instead:

```
image <- image_read("./path/image.jpeg")
```

If it doesn't read, then as some of the comments say it may not be the right format.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you! Could you potentially explain what was wrong with the way I was doing it earlier? I am new to R and am trying to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure myself, but I know that Magick uses its own specified file type. I recommend checking this post for more info on quality improvement in Magick images: https://ropensci.org/technotes/2017/08/17/tesseract-16/ ; there are more process steps as well which can be added in the pipeline.

Comment: @BillNorris, would you mind to select the response as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I just saw this, just approved it as the appropriate response. thank you for your help!